# AngularJS defer did'n return variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I not understand why my function does not set my global variable. My code:

```
 var localizeRegForm = {};


 var handlerLocalDef = function(defer) {
     var hash;

     defer.then(
         function(response) {
             return hash = response.data;
         },
         function(err) {
             showPopup(err);
         }
      );

      return hash;
  };

  var initialized = function() {
      console.log("localizeRegForm",localizeRegForm); 
      localizeRegForm = handlerLocalDef(Localization.getLocalizedDefer('regularform'));
      console.log("localizeRegForm",localizeRegForm)
  }
```

My console show:

1. `localizeRegForm Object {}`
2. `localizeRegForm undefined`

Answer (score 0):

it's better to rewrite it:

```
        var initialized = function()  { 
                Localization.getLocalizedDefer('regularform').then(function(response){
                    localizeRegForm = response.data;
                    console.log("localizeRegForm",localizeRegForm)
                });
             }
```

and the question is not about AngularJS, 
it's more about using defered object

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'something',
            data: data
        }).
        success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).
        error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject("");
        })
        return deferred.promise;
```